# Trying to access database from my local server

Tags: python, django, server, zoho

I want to access a database from Zoho Creator using their REST API (https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-add-records.html) I read that I cannot do that from the client side (because CORS isnt implemented or something along those lines) and that I would have to do it from a server.

So I setup a local server using django and I ran a script from the terminal that should add a record to my zoho database, but it doesnt work...

I'm not sure if the script is wrong or if the way I use the server is wrong.

The server is ran by django, I made a simple server with the command "django-admin startproject mysite" and ran the server with "python manage.py runserver".

The name of the app is "synonyms-database", the form is "Main_Form" and the only field there is is called "name". So with that info I followed the API instructions and this is my script:

```
import requests

payload = {'authtoken': myAPIToken, 'scope': 'creatorapi', 'name': 'test'}
response = requests.request('POST', 
'https://creator.zoho.com/api/erik341/json/synonyms- 
database/form/Main_Form/record/add/', json=payload)

print(response.headers)
print(response.text)
print(response.url)
```

And I get this response:

```
<body>
    <div>
        An error has occurred. It has been reported to Zoho Creator 
        support. We will look into this issue .<br> Sorry for the 
        inconvenience caused.
        <p><p>
        Go to <a href='%2F'>Home</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

If instead of json=payload I use data=payload the response changes to:

```
{"code":2945,"message":"INVALID_TICKET"}
```

Comment: What is the status code that you receiving?

Comment: The sample request shows an HTML form, so it looks as if the data should be form-encoded. That means you should use `data=payload` not `json=payload`. If you search for "INVALID_TICKET" there seem to be many results - [one suggestion](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/getting-invalid-ticket-id-error) I saw was to try regenerating the token.

Comment: Okay I feel really stupid... for some reason when I found the link you sent me, I just read the part of recreating the token, which didnt work... but I now changed the url to .eu instead of .com and the new message is an error about not setting the value of the field 'Name' which I solved by changing from 'name' to 'Name'.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There seemed to be a lot of pages about `INVALID_TOKEN` - glad you found the answer that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expects form-encoded data so you should use `data=payload` instead of `json=payload`. The `json` in the URL is the format for the response format, not the request.

You might be able to solve the `INVALID_TICKET` error by regenerating the token. There's a comment on [this post](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/getting-invalid-ticket-id-error) which solved the error by changing the URL from `.eu` to `.com`. Make sure that you generate the auth token on a URL that matches your request URL.